# Detect large of damage money

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on an app to detect "damage amount" of paper money. 
The app will assess the user's input image, and confirm if they have rights to a replacement note.

The output is : `if 30% of lost of money object, can allow changing at the bank`.

[image]

I have idea, we make capture with camera of money and the damage background is white so, in AS3 can count how percent of white color. If less then 30% so is good to change on the Bank.

Any idea (calculation) of how to count percentage of white colour in image?. Thanks.

**-- EDIT --**

i have the code @VC.One, may you make correction? Thanks.

```
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    var camMoney: Camera = Camera.getCamera();
    camMoney.setQuality(0, 100);
    camMoney.setMode(480, 300, 30, true);
    var vidMoney: Video = new Video(480, 300)
    vidMoney.x = 0;
    vidMoney.y = 10;
    addChild(vidMoney);
    vidMoney.attachCamera(camMoney);

    var moneyBD: BitmapData = new BitmapData(vidMoney.width, vidMoney.height);

    var moneyBM: Bitmap = new Bitmap(moneyBD);
    moneyBM.x = 0;
    moneyBM.y = 376;
    addChild(moneyBM);

    var circle: Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFFFFFF);
    circle.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(225, 340, 20);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(circle);
    circle.buttonMode = true;
    circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, capture);
    function capture(e: MouseEvent): void {
        moneyBD.draw(vidMoney);
    }

    var circleRect: Sprite = new Sprite();
    circleRect.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFFFFFF);
    circleRect.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    circleRect.graphics.drawRoundRect(260, 320, 60, 40, 30);
    circleRect.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(circleRect);
    circleRect.buttonMode = true;
    circleRect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, analisa);
    function analisa(e: MouseEvent): void {
        var xi: int;
        var yi: int;
        var pixel: uint;
        var color: uint;
        var pointsWhite: Array = [];
        for (xi = 0; xi = 2) {
            var lengthOfWhiteSpace: int = pointGroup[pointGroup.length - 1].x - pointGroup[0].x;
            var t: TextField = new TextField();
            t.x = pointGroup[0].x;
            t.y = pointGroup[0].y;
            addChild(t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a bitmapdata object, here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Comment: thanks @Jezzamon. i try it now.

Comment: Have you worked with pixels before? In that Bitmpdata API link, you might want to check `histogram` or even just use `getPixel` (which tells you colour from a tested pixel position). Use a `For` loop to scan each pixel and test if it matches white (`0xFFFFF`) so logic like this : `if white == myBMPdata.getPixel( i, j ) then { so add +1 to totalWhitePixels };`. When the scan is finished compare your **total image pixels** vs **total white pixels**, use math to calculate percentage.

Comment: thanks @VC.One for your edited and the answer. I work now. Thnk you for  a briliant solution

Comment: @VC.One can you correct my AS3:

Comment: @Asrul To allow changing at the bank, are you looking for **more than 30%** damage to paper? Or you want changing if **less than**? Your question is unclear. Re-read the words & correct anything

Comment: Thanks @VC.One I try now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage formula is : `amountFound * 100 / amountTotal`

For example if you have $200 put somewhere but only found $50. Doing `50 * 100 / 200` tells that you found 25%. If you found another $50 (now $100), it tells you that you got 50% of your $200.

With this basic formula, you can use it like this for your `Analisa` function...

```
function analisa(e:MouseEvent = null) : void 
{
    var xi: int=0; var yi: int=0; var pixel: uint=0;

    var totalPixels_image : int = 0;
    var totalPixels_white : int = 0;
    var PercentWhitePixels : Number = 0;

    //# get total pixels
    totalPixels_image = bmpData.width * bmpData.height;

    //# get total white pixels
    for (yi = 0; yi < bmpData.height; yi++) 
    {
        for (xi = 0; xi < bmpData.width; xi++) 
        {
            pixel = bmpData.getPixel( xi, yi );

            if ( pixel == 0xFFFFFF)
            {
                totalPixels_white += 1; //++;
            }
        }
    }

    PercentWhitePixels = ( (totalPixels_white * 100) / totalPixels_image);

    //# get results 
    trace("=== RESULTS =================================");
    trace("Image Width  : " + bmpData.width );
    trace("Image Height : " + bmpData.height );
    trace("total Pixels in Image  : " + totalPixels_image);
    trace("total Pixels of White  : " + totalPixels_white);
    trace("Percentage of White    : " + PercentWhitePixels) + "%";

}
```

For me the result for your image was **0.1895...**. But from looking with my eyes I think a number around 5% to 10% *looks* more correct (not this calculated 0.18%). If you multiply result by 100 it will become `18.95%` but now that seems too much.

I think an extra or different calculation is needed, I will update when I think of something later but this Answer should help you start..

PS consider checking about :

**1)** [**Percentage: Difference vs Error**](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/percentage-difference-vs-error.html). 
**2)** I think [**Percentage Difference**](https://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html) might help you.

Comment: I think the problem is simply that white isn't the best color to check against. It needs to be a color that has no chance of appearing anywhere on the note, like 0x00FF00 I guess. Although personally I think ~18% isn't too far off, for me it looks like roughly a fifth of the note is missing if you put the white spaces next to each other.

Comment: @DodgerThud, well Asker said it was for a bank, so I can only assume they already have this part thought about. In Google Images, that shown paper note **does actually have white** so dunno if the end-client's scanning equipment will somehow tint the picture (coloured light?) but still put scanned pixels on a white background. I agree that preparation of materials & equipment before checking is important.

Comment: @VC.One i just Try the code and the problem is, the bitmapdata from camera is not pure white 0xffffff, So i has Solution to make ranges from 0xffffff to grey 10% or other, So can you help Me?

Comment: @Asrul Show me a link to your example camera image.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One for you quick respon. This my link sample image from app camera : http://i67.tinypic.com/2j5jfhl.jpg and please give me too, how to store image after capture on device and send by default email on android. Thanks.

Comment: For email & storing to disk / SD card, you'll have to ask a new Question. It's not my area. I'll think of something about your colour ranges. Probably you want to create an option for user to mark background pixels (like magic wand). There is an AS3 example code somewhere if you try Google search. Anyways what if there is too much background (or zoomed out)? To avoid issues : maybe design your user-interface to tell user to try "fit" the corners of money inside on-screen drawing of box shape, then after photo taking, they also "click" on missing or damage parts. Then you analyse clicked parts.

Comment: Ok @VC.One your Solution is same with my idea too but the banking management want the easy use tool without brush magic, but I try later. Thanks again.

Comment: @VC.One i had solution. I just edit brightness bitmap until get white pixel. But the problem is, getpixel just for bitmapdata. Are you know AS3 edit brightness for bitmapdata? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

The OP, new to SOF, accidentally added additional question info in as an answer. I moved it into an edit under the OP because I do not have rights to delete this "answer".

Comment: Thanks for editing @Jacksonkr. I need this logic code : Use a For loop to scan each pixel and test if it matches white (0xFFFFF) so logic like this : if white == myBMPdata.getPixel( i, j ) then { so add +1 to totalWhitePixels };. When the scan is finished compare your total image pixels vs total white pixels, use math to calculate percentage